# Convert JSON field to key value pair in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have predictions stored in a JSON field in a mysql table as follow

```
SELECT id, value from predictions

id | value                 |
+--------------------------+
1  | {"class1": 0.99, "class2": 0.05}
2  | {"class1": 0.94, "class2": 0.01, "class3": 0.4}
...
```

Each row contains a dictionary with (potentially) different keys, but each dictionnary follows this schema.

I'd like to deserialize this into a key-value result like below:

```
id | class  | confidence |
+------------------------+
1  | class1 | 0.99       |
1  | class2 | 0.05       |
2  | class1 | 0.94       |
2  | class2 | 0.01       |
2  | class3 | 0.4        |
```

Were the JSON in the format of a list containing one dictionary for each predicted class, I could have used the `JSON_TABLE` as I am using MySQL > 8.0, however I am at a loss on how to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using MySql 8.0 you can use `JSON_KEYS()`, `JSON_EXTRACT()` and `JSON_TABLE` for your requirement like below:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    class, 
    json_extract(value_,concat('$.',class)) confidence 
from test t1
cross join 
    json_table(
        json_keys(value_)
        , '$[*]' columns(class varchar(10) path '$')
    ) t2
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1c0eaace8ff2ed1ed7e6cbeb2749960a)

Comment: Great, thank you ! For future readers, note that if your class name contains spaces, the json path created in the JSON_EXTRACT needs to be encapsulated in double quotes as follow `CONCAT('$."', class, '"')`

Comment: Another question out of curiosity: is the cast of the json_keys as json necessary ? I tested without it on my use case and it works fine

Comment: It is not mandatory. Actually JSON_KEYS() return is sufficient.